# How to Integrate Live search in WordPress?

Tags: search

I tried most of the available plugins to integrate Live Search in WordPress, but all of them messed up my theme layout.

The search function in my site is from a small search box at the top right using the following code in `header.php`:

```
<div id="search">
    <div class="search-content">
        <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://example.com/">
            <input class="form-control search-input" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Search..', 'demotheme'); ?>" name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far I have tested these plugins:

- Dave's WordPress Live Search
- Ajax Search for WooCommerce
- Ajax Search Lite
- SearchWP Live Ajax Search
- Advanced Woo Search
- Ivory Search – WordPress Search Plugin

Every time I try to replace the default search function `<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>` in the header file with the plugin shortcode, I got the following mess in my theme:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Which plugins have you used so far? What did they *mess up* in your theme layout? Sharing a link or screenshot would be a better idea to understand the issue.

Comment: What is live search? Keep in mind that plugin recommendations are off topic here and not in scope of this stack

Comment: post updated with new information